# How to read NVDA speech viewer's text output stream using Python API

Tags: accessibility, screen-readers, nvda, accessibility-api

I am making a desktop app which requires listening to the continuous text output stream of **NVDA screen viewer**. How to do it with their Python API?

```
# event which is triggered when a new 
# text line appears in NVDA Speech Viewer
def on_new_text_line(text):
    do_something(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:-
https://github.com/prut-h7/NVDA_Speech_Broadcaster

It broadcasts the text stream via UDP, so simply create a receiver port to capture the text output. It is platform independent, so you can use any preferred language to capture the output. And suggest any changes/updates if needed !